# Is it ok to combine machines with DNS server management and machines that do host lookups through a hosts file?

Tags: linux, rhel, dns, hosts, resolv.conf

We have a cluster of Linux machines.

DNS of these machines is managed by a DNS server (a Windows machine with DNS records).

Now we want to add an additional cluster with Linux machines
that would do host lookups from `/etc/hosts` instead.

Both clusters should be able to talk to each other.

Is this ok?

Comment: It's also easy to combine both `/etc/hosts` lookup and a DNS server e.g. with `dnsmasq`, so you can configure the additional cluster (or give it the DHCP info) to just use an (additional) DNS server running `dnsmasq`, and using the Windows DNS server as upstream. (Or you could replace the Windows DNS server by the machine running `dnsmasq`).

Comment: @dirkt, that won't help the first cluster, which is already using the Windows DNS. A proper delegation would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On one level this is a policy decision and nothing to do with the technology.

On another level you should be asking yourselves why you don't want this second cluster properly supported by your systems administration staff.

Finally, to answer the question as asked: yes it's possible, but the names of the systems will be available only to those systems with a modified `/etc/hosts`. Everything else will have to use IP addresses to reference your new cluster. It's rather a high adminstrative overhead for no apparent advantage.

Note that if you want to retain control of the name/address mapping, there's little technical reason why you couldn't create your cluster as a DNS subdomain and have the main DNS servers delegate to your own DNS servers for that subdomain. Everyone gets the benefits of DNS and you retain control over your subdomain.

Technical recommendation? Do it properly and use DNS.